# Не запускается JSF страница

Tags: java, jsf

сижу учу Джаву, полностью следую курсу, но не получается запустить JSF страницу. Ни собственную, ни прилагающуюся к курсу.
Изначально запускал на Томкате, но потом оказалось, что он не поддерживает CDI
Потом скачал Glassfish, но оказалось, что версия 5.0 не работает с новыми JDK.
Скачал старый JDK8 с сайта оракла, и всё равно ничего не работает. Теперь получаю сообщение:

> [2020-11-28 11:30:29,253] Artifact JSF-App-Ex:war exploded: Artifact
> is being deployed, please wait... [2020-11-28 11:30:32,664] Artifact
> JSF-App-Ex:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server
> log for details. [2020-11-28 11:30:32,665] Artifact JSF-App-Ex:war
> exploded: java.io.IOException:
> com.sun.enterprise.admin.remote.RemoteFailureException: Error occurred
> during deployment: Exception while deploying the app [JSF-App] :
> org.xml.sax.SAXParseExceptionpublicId:
> file:/C:/Users/Пан%20Дарси/Downloads/glassfish-5.0.1/glassfish5/glassfish/lib/schemas/web-app_2_5.xsd;
> lineNumber: 1117; columnNumber: 49; Deployment descriptor file
> WEB-INF/web.xml in archive [JSF-App].  src-resolve: Cannot resolve the
> name 'javaee:descriptionGroup' to a(n) 'group' component.. Please see
> server.log for more details.

Как можно решить эту проблему? И что это вообще за проблема?

Comment: Русские символы в пути?

Comment: да, русские символы в пути. неужели в 2020-м приложения от крупнейших компаний до сих пор не умеют в символы, кроме латиницы?

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, это решение поможет: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56736795/1341148 .

Там суть в том, что некоторые пространства имён (namespace-ы) и их адреса в Сети поменялись после перехода `Java` из Sun в Oracle. Сервер приложений при разборе `XML`-файлов (например, дескриптора развёртывания приложения - `web.xml`) нередко скачивает их `XSD`-схему (указанную в заголовке самого `XML`-файла) и сверяет по ней валидность содержания `XML`-файла. Судя по всему, Ваш курс чуточку устарел в этом плане, и смена адресов `XSD`-схем не учтена.

Перед тем, как что-то менять, можно попробовать просто отключить Интернет на компьютере, тогда внешние ресурсы (.xsd) станут недоступными. Зачастую, недоступные `XSD`-схемы просто игнорируются, а вот те, что вроде доступны, но при скачивании возвращают неверный контент - приводят к сбою.

Comment: Ну курс прошлого года, но там рассматриваются устаревшие технологии для полноты информации видимо.
Спасибо за совет! Эта проблема исправилась сама собой (обожаю эту детерминированность в программировании). Исключение больше не появляется, но приложение всё ещё не работает - буду разбираться дальше)

Answer (score 0):

Ну, Tomcat отлично работает с CDI бинами. Проблемы могут быть при использовании EJB.  Похожая ошибка может возникать, если приложение работает с базой данных и есть ошибки в настройках соединения или структуры таблиц.

Comment: везде пишут, что он не работает с CDI, Что такое EJB я не знаю. с базой данной приложение не работает, это обычное хеллоу ворлд. Там всего две страницы, одна кнопка и одно текстовое поле)